# trailing numbers after converting negative to positive number

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my version of `printf` in C.
Everything is working except for when I try to print a negative number, something is not working and it prints a few garbage numbers after the number I want.

Here is the code:

```c
const char g_chars[] = "0123456789abcdef";

void printf_unsigned(unsigned int num, int base) {
    char string[32];
    int pos = 0;

    do {
        int rem = num % base;
        num /= base;
        string[pos++] = g_chars[rem];
    } while (num > 0);

    while (--pos >= 0) {
        PrintChar(string[pos]);
    }
}

void printf_signed(int num, int base) {
    if (num < 0) {
        PrintChar('-');
        printf_unsigned(num * -1, base);
    }
    printf_unsigned(num, base);
}
```

`printf_unsigned` converts the binary number to its ASCII representation and prints it char by char, and it is working.
The `printf_signed` function checks if a number is negative, if it's not it just calls `printf_unsigned`, otherwise it prints a leading `-` and then calls `printf_unsigned` with the number multiplied by `-1`.
But when I try to call the `printf_signed` function with negative numbers it prints out what I want but then it adds some garbage to it.
example:

```c
printf_signed(-3, 10);
printf_signed(-10, 10);
printf_signed(-15, 10);
```

output:

```
-34294967293
-104294967286
-154294967281
```

Comment: You are calling the function printf_unsigned two times  for a negative number   if (num < 0){
        PrintChar('-');
        printf_unsigned(num*-1, base);
    }
    printf_unsigned(num, base); And the second time a signed number is outputted as  unsigned. Instead of the if statement use if-else statement.

Comment: Note that 4294967281+15 = 4294967296 = 2^32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I forgot the else statment...
The function should look like this insetad:

```
void printf_signed(int num, int base){
    if (num < 0){
        PrintChar('-');
        printf_unsigned(num*-1, base);
    } else {
        printf_unsigned(num, base);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a typical programming error so don't feel bad.  There are two types of programmers - those who write code with stupid bugs in it that are obvious to others, and liars.  :-D

Comment: Hey, not everyone's a liar. Some of us are just hopelessly naive.

Comment: Curious, why `printf_unsigned(num * -1, base)` and not `printf_unsigned(-num, base)`?

Comment: Note that `num*-1` and `-num` are both _undefined behavior_ (UB) when `num == INT_MIN`.